# ¿Como Convertir un List<Tennat> a List<TennatDTO> con AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Como se puede convertir un listado de entidades a un listado de DTOS, cuando utilizo Automapper para convertir una sola entidad me funciona pero cuando utilizo autoMapper para convertir de listado a listado no me funciona.

El codigo no genera ninguna excepción, pero la variable **tenantDTO** termina con 0 elementos.

Estoy utilizando .net core.

**Código donde convierto de Listado a Listado**

```
            List<Tenant> entities = new List<Tenant>();
           entities = _tenantData.GetAllBy(x=>x.CompanyId== claimCompanyId && x.Active ==true).ToList();

            if (entities != null && entities.Count >=1)
            {                
                List<TenantDTO> tenantDTO = _mapper.Map<List<TenantDTO>>(entities);              


                return tenantDTO;
            }
```

**Startup**

```
            //Se configura el Automapper
            var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new AutomapperProfile());


            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

**Perfil de AutoMapper**

```
namespace Business.Automapper
{
    public class AutomapperProfile:Profile
    {    
            public AutomapperProfile()
            {
                CreateMap<User, UserDTO>().ReverseMap();
                CreateMap<List<User>, List<UserDTO>>().ReverseMap();

                CreateMap<Company, CompanyDTO>().ReverseMap();
                CreateMap<List<Company>, List<CompanyDTO>>().ReverseMap();

                CreateMap<Tenant, TenantDTO>().ReverseMap();
                CreateMap<List<Tenant>, List<TenantDTO>>().ReverseMap();
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucione este problema, quitando la siguiente linea del **perfil del Automapper**:

```
CreateMap<List<Tenant>, List<TenantDTO>>().ReverseMap();
```

Al parecer no es necesario indicar a autoMapper que necesitamos convertir un listado de entidades cuando ya indicamos la entidad.